# 'Subscript out of range' problem when calling a subroutine

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a subscript out of range error when calling a subroutine that resides in a different sheet, using a button click event. When I call that same subroutine with the button on that same page it works fine. I am also calling a different subroutine from a different page in the same way and that works fine as well so I'm a little frustrated/confused as to what the issue is with this particular subroutine call.  `Call Sheet13.SolveOPandI` is what's being highlighted/flagged.

```
Private Sub Btn_Solve_Click()
Dim ftype As String
Dim i As Integer

Call Sheet13.SolveOPandI

Sheet30.CheckBoxvi.value = False
Sheet30.CheckBoxmass.value = False

Call Sheet30.RangeCalc

For i = 1 To 5
Sheet9.Range("FVD_distance").MergeArea.value = Sheet2.Cells(49 + i, 4).value
Sheet17.Cells(36, 2 + i).value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheet9.Range("Q8:Q13").value)
Sheet17.Cells(37, 2 + i).value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Sheet9.Range("Q8:Q13").value)
Next i


Sheet17.Activate

End Sub
```

If I comment out that subroutine call, the rest of the script runs fine including calling the other subroutine `Call Sheet30.RangeCalc`.
Below is the code for the subroutine in question:

```
Public Sub SolveOPandI()
Dim Pso_bar, Ro_bar, Rbar, gamma, p1, pa, Pi As Double
Dim gtype As String

'define pi
Pi = Application.WorksheetFunction.Pi()

gtype = Sheet2.Range("ideal").value
'spec. heat ratio, tank and ambient pressures from Input sheet
p1 = Sheet2.Range("D18").value
pa = Sheet2.Range("D20").value
gamma = Sheet2.Range("D26").value

'set initial guess Ps to 1
Range("D5").value = 1

'iterate with solver for Pso-bar
SolverOk SetCell:=Range("C5"), MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=Range("D5")
SolverSolve

Pso_bar = Range("D10").value 'start overpressure
Ro_bar = 1 / ((4 * Pi / 3) * (p1 / pa - 1) / (gamma - 1)) ^ (1 / 3) 'start scaled distance
Range("D12").value = Ro_bar

Call R_Baker134906(Pso_bar, Ro_bar)
Call impulse
Call GCF
Call WST


End Sub
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Change your error handling option to "Break in class module" (VBA editor >> Tools >> Options >> General tab >> Error Trapping) and see what changes.  With that error the problem may be here: `Sheet2.Range("ideal")` (no range with that name on Sheet2)

Comment: I did as you suggested and now the error shows up in one of the subroutines being called by the subroutine in question. The subscript out of range error is for a variable being calculated. If I run this exact same subscript from the pages it is in it runs without error. Another point of interest is the fact that it is somehow skipping to the line where this other subroutine is called before calling the iterative Solver which I am calling several lines before (result in a pop-up when it's done but I am not seeing it).

Comment: "If I run this exact same subscript from the pages it is in it runs without error" - maybe suggests a default Range/Cells scope problem - make sure all Range/Cells calls are fully-qualified.  Not much else to offer without seeing the problem code.

Comment: Hi Tim, here's the code for that function: